# Il a été capturé / il est capturé

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, passif

I was reading a French article and I came upon this structure a few times:

> Il a été capturé.

But in school, for what I can remember we were only taught this:

> Il est capturé.

So what is the actual difference in meaning and when should these structures be used? This incertitude remains as we didn't really used the first one in school;  I noticed however that they are often used in articles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are *passive constructions* in the *passé composé* and *indicatif présent* tenses, respectively. No adjectives are involved whatsoever. The difference between them two is one of tense. The second one would be more accurately translated as *He's being/getting caught*.

In French the passive is constructed by following the corresponding conjugation of *être* with the past participle of the verb. Note that in such construction, the past participle must agree in gender and number with the subject.

Comment: @PaulPicard I agree that *il est capturé* is unidiomatic (but grammatical) and a number of other formulations would be better choices. I considered pointing it out, but it wasn't directly related to the question.

Answer (score 5):

*NOTE: french is my mother language, it's why I can respond.

But english is NOT, so apologies in advance for this aspect :-)*

Although previous answers are correct, it seems important to mention something else.

There is a difference between two kinds of verbs, natively rather appropriated for designate either an action/event (what is currently happening) or a result/situation (what is the state due to a previous action/event).

In the case of *capturer*, which belongs to the first kind above, *il a été capturé* is the most natural way to use it: it describes an event which already happened (and the result is something like *il est prisonnier*).

At the opposite, *il est capturé* may be rarely used: only in a special way to tell the story, where tense is always *présent de l'indicatif*, often for a dramatical effect.
Example for the "whole" story: *Il est poursuivi. Il tombe, il se relève... Mais il est rattrapé: ça y est, il est capturé !*

Comment: Nice explanation! I'm wondering if "est capturé" can also be used (as "is captured" can be in English) in a quasi "conditional" sense like "If/when he is captured [he will be punished]" (quand/s'il est capturé ...) or does one have to use the future/conditional tense in that "si/quand" clause? (or would you try to avoid "si/quand" completely and say "Une fois capturé...."?) (or something else?) Thanks

Comment: @PapaPoule: in fact, you may use either formulation, with a subtle difference. 1. In most cases, where we are drawing plans for a precise action targetting a given person, we'll say "s'il est capturé / quand il sera capturé". 2. The other style applies if we are talking about the general rules to follow in such occasions: "s'il est capturé / quand il est capturé".

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you're using the verb *être* with an adjective (*capturé*). The first one uses past tense (*passé composé*, *he has been caught*) the second one uses present tense (*he is caught*).

The difference in meaning is nothing more than the tense.